# Joomla, notices after installation

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I am having some issues after installing joomla, what should be done to remove this? I have attached the image of what I am getting.[image]

Comment: Is this a vanilla install?  Does Joomla have permissions to read files?

Comment: have you downloaded the latest version of Joomla (2.5.6)? and what version of MySQL and PHP do you have? and have you edited any core Joomla files?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're running PHP 5.4. Joomla 2.5 isn't yet completely compatible with that version yet. There are patches in the tracker right now to fix these issues, hopefully they'll be in 2.5.7.